# Authentication within Azure cloud

Tags: azure, authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication to my web API. I need to firstly authenticate one user to access some methods. I use the Azure AD, an automatic tool in Azure. The problem is that when I try it in Soap UI, I get the error bellow:

> Org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException:
>   Error: Unexpected element: CDATA

And I guess the problem is that it returns the login page of Microsoft.

I'm sorry for not putting some code here or maybe any other detail, but I am really messy about this.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass in the `Authorization: Bearer` header. If you `curl -iI http://yourWebApi.azurewebsites.net` do you get a `403 Forbidden` back or a redirect? Did you use Easy Auth to protect your API with Azure AD? (Easy Auth == the Authentication/Authorization blade in the Portal). Or did you configure it through ADAL/OWIN in your application code?

Comment: Hello @evilSnobu I have used the Easy Auth.

Comment: I'm using Windows, but if I open the URL on browser it is redirected to a Microsoft login page.

Comment: In Soap UI, are you sure you're sending the `Authorization: Bearer` header with your request?

Comment: @evilSnobu, no, I'm not sure. I just try to connect to the service with the wsdl part in the url.

Comment: You definitely need to be sure because it won't allow unauthenticated calls given that you've enabled Easy Auth.